# listening to javascript custom event inside vuejs component

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

I created a custom event and dispatched it in my main page script, which includes a Vue component. How do I listen to that event from inside the Vue component?

*main.blade.php:*

```html
<body>
   <insert-block></insert-block>
   <script>
      const insert_block_event = new CustomEvent('insert_block', { detail: 'some detail goes here' });
      document.body.dispatchEvent(insert_block_event);
   </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're dispatching on `document.body`, your component could listen to the event on `document.body` with [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) in the `mounted()` hook, and [`removeEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener) in the `beforeDestroy()` hook:

```js
// MyComponent.vue
export default {
  mounted() {
    document.body.addEventListener('insert_block', this.onInsertBlock)
  },
  beforeDestroy() {
    document.body.removeEventListener('insert_block', this.onInsertBlock)
  },
  methods: {
    onInsertBlock(e) {
      console.log('insert_block', e)
    }
  }
}
```